# Retrieving data from database using PHP script on different server

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

So I am trying to find a solution to a bit of a tricky problem.

I need data from a postgres DB for use in a script on server 1. Server 1 does not have postgres libraries installed.

Server 2 has postgres libraries installed. I would like to write a script on server 2 that retrieves the information after having been passed the correct parameters. Although I am not sure hot to get that info to server 1.

Am I right in assuming I cannot use include cross-domain? security wise etc.

I considered using javascript and modal dialogs (we use old old IE) to open the page and return the data via window.returnValue, but this seems messy and convoluted.

Is there a better way of doing this?

**Update: Found a solution**

I created a web service on server 2 that would run the query required, and return the results, then just called it from server 1.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

Yes, there is a better way, use an API for that.
One can take a look at Apigility (https://www.apigility.org/) to have a start.

In short: On Server 2, you implement an API that handles the request (and not forget about security like auth and so on) and resturns it. Server 1 sends a request to that API on Server 2 and gets the answer from there.

I hope, this will guide you in the right direction.

There is another solution: You can open Server 2 not only to answer querys from localhost but from server 1 too. This is not the safest way, but possible, so you can query Server 2 directly from server 1 (just enter it's DNS in db-config).